# How to separate surefire report into 2 or more categories?

Tags: junit, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-site-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I want to separate tests into 3 different categories:

- unit
- componnet
- system

Then I want to run them separately on different phases and display results of execution these tests into 3 different surefire reports, or maybe one but with tests resultsd divided into 3 different catagories.

How to achieve it with maven?

I know I can run tests separately using failsafe maven plugin. So it is not problem.

There only problem have I can devide report into 3 catagories.

Comment: I am using maven-surefire-plugin with jUnit annotations.

Answer (score 3):

I am using maven-surefire-plugin with junit categories.

```
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unit-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>com.mycompany.mavenproject2.UnitTest</groups> 
                        <reportsDirectory> ${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/unit</reportsDirectory> 
                        <reportNameSuffix>UNIT</reportNameSuffix>      
                    </configuration>     
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>comp-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>com.mycompany.mavenproject2.ComponentTest</groups>
                        <reportsDirectory> ${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/comp</reportsDirectory> 
                        <reportNameSuffix>COMPONENT</reportNameSuffix>                
                    </configuration>     
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>sys-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>com.mycompany.mavenproject2.SystemTest</groups>
                        <reportsDirectory> ${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/sys</reportsDirectory>
                        <reportNameSuffix>SYSTEM</reportNameSuffix>                  
                    </configuration>     
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

*It works fine,except that it run first all tests not separating them into categories.*
**How to remove such behaviour?**

### Build produced an output.

### T E S T S

Running com.mycompany.mavenproject2.AppTest
UnitTest
ComponentTest
SystemTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.031 sec

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[surefire:test]
Surefire report directory: C:\Users\mz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject2\target\surefire-reports\unit

---

### T E S T S

Concurrency config is parallel='none', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running com.mycompany.mavenproject2.AppTest
UnitTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[surefire:test]
Surefire report directory: C:\Users\mz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject2\target\surefire-reports\comp

---

### T E S T S

Concurrency config is parallel='none', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running com.mycompany.mavenproject2.AppTest
ComponentTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[surefire:test]
Surefire report directory: C:\Users\mz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject2\target\surefire-reports\sys

---

### T E S T S

Concurrency config is parallel='none', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running com.mycompany.mavenproject2.AppTest
SystemTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: Your default configuration needs to exclude all groups that you want to run later on.  So in your top level configuration (before execution blocks) - define an <excludesGroups> block that lists all your groups